# Cut part of path in CSV without deleting rest of csv file

Tags: bash, csv, directory, path

I have CSV file which looks like that:

```
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project1/Assets/file.ttf,Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project2/Assets/file2.ttf,Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
```

I need to change the path to users/my/temporaryprojects/project1 + rest of CSV data, users/my/temporaryprojects/project2 + rest of CSV data etc... . I was trying to do different bash scripts like

```
cut -d'/' -f 5- newTTF-Projects-INFO.csv >> ONETTF-Projects-INFO.csv
```

But unfortunately every time the script is deleting everything which is after the first comma separated value:

```
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project1
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project2
```

I need it to be in this format:

```
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project1, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project2, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
```

I need to shorter the path to file which is on the first place and leave as it is every other data. I know that every time I need only 4 first parts of the value. I was trying to do this all night long with "cut", "sed", "awk" but I don't have my result. Every method is deleting values after the first comma.  Could somebody help me? I did not find any answer to my question. The file to edit has a lot of rows like the one in example.

Comment: a simple `sed 's#^[^,]*/#my/new/path/#' newTTF-Projects-INFO.csv` should be enough

Comment: @Fravadona I have change my question a little bit, sorry for my misexplaining. I need to have the exact paths that are exactly like those one in the CSV and also there are different paths in the file. I just need the 4 first parts of the paths and the rest of CSV data as it is. But I appreciate your answer it's actually the closest one to my problem :)

Comment: Is it possible that the first field is quoted? This would be the case for instance if one of the pathes contains a comma.

Comment: no, it's not quoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'~\(\(/[^/]*\)\{4\}\)[^,]*,~\1, ~' input_file
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project1, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project2, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
```

Answer (score 0):

- *`backreferences`-capable* `regex` engine not needed at all for this barebones `awk`-solution
- *straight up cleaning* `FS` *to* `OFS`

**CODE**

```
echo "${input}" | 

mawk NF=NF FS='[/][^,\\/]*[/][^,\\/]*[,]' OFS=', '

           or simply just

gawk NF=NF FS='[/][^,/]*[/][^,/]*[,]' OFS=', '
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project1, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project2, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v level="2" '
  function dirname(f,l) {
    s = ""; n=split(f,a,"/");
    for (i=2; i<=n-l; i++) {  s = s "/" a[i] }
    return s
  }
  function basename(f) {
    n=split(f,a,"/");return a[n]
  }
  BEGIN{ OFS=FS }
  {$1=dirname($1,level); $2=" "$2}1
' input_file

/users/my/temporaryprojects/project1, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
/users/my/temporaryprojects/project2, Arial Unicode MS,Regular,Arial Unicode MS,ArialUnicodeMS,Version 1.01x,Monotype
```